# Returning Hex UUID as default value for Django model charfield

Tags: python, django, hex, uuid

I tried to create a model with identifier generated from uuid4. But what I want instead of regular uuid, I want identifier has hex uuid format (without "-"). Here is what I tried:

```
class Model(models.Model):

    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4().hex, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.identifier

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

instead of returning unique id every time inherited class instantiated, it returns the same id because of `uuid4()`. I tried to change the default value from `uuid.uuid4().hex` to `uuid.uuid4.hex` but it seems the `hex` is not callable from `uuid4` directly. So what is the possible way to produce default value for my identifier from uuid with hex format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>You need to make it callable</s>

```
default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex
```

**UPDATE**

As @ZulwiyozaPutra noted. Solution fails while migration, what i am totally forgot is that Django cannot serialize Lambdas.

Solution would be defining new function with desired behavior:

```
def hex_uuid():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex
```

and using this function as default argument **as callable**:

```
identifier = models.CharField(default=hex_uuid, ...)
```

Comment: But it returns an error when I tried to migrate my data. It gives me ```"Cannot serialize function: lambda"```

Comment: @ZulwiyozaPutra i've forgot about that, i've updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Model(models.Model):

    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

if you use uuid.uuid4() the function will be executed on runserver, just give the signature and django will do the rest.

Comment: `uuid.uuid4` will generate a value of 36 characters and that field has at most 31 characters (I wasn't the downvoter though).

Comment: Even if one does `uuid.uuid4().hex` in a function, it'll be 32 which is more than at most 31 characters.