# How to have models.UUIDField field without dash

Tags: python, django

I tried to have `models.UUIDField` without dash, by using `default=uuid.uuid4().hex` (Instead of `default=uuid.uuid4()`)

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    api_key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4().hex, editable=False, unique=True)
    subscription = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[(s.value, s.name) for s in Subscription],
        null=False,
        blank=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.api_key)
```

However, the resultant result still come with dash.

```
django=# select * from users_profile;
 id |               api_key                | secret_key | subscription | user_id
----+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------+---------
  1 | 9da3546c-660c-46c6-adc4-6a13e6ee202b |            |            0 |       1
  2 | 9cbc3a68-7f50-4b18-9e61-7b009f22a0e8 |            |            0 |       2
(2 rows)
```

**May I know how to have models.UUIDField field without dash?**. I would like to store in database without dashes, and use it without dashes.

Comment: try this => https://stackoverflow.com/a/48438640/8150371

Comment: This question can mean two things: do you want to *store it in the database* without dashes, or *use it in Django* without dashes?

Comment: Both,  I would like to store in database without dashes, and use it without dashes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you using PostgreSQL by any chance? The `UUIDField` may be using the native [`uuid` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) for the column. It stores it efficiently using only 16 bytes (without dashes). If that is the case, it is **not** storing the dashes, only showing them when you `select`.

The good news is that in Python code you are getting a [`UUID` object](https://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID), so you can do `self.api_key.hex` to get a string without dashes.

Answer (score 7):

Use **`CharField`** field instead of `UUIDField`,

```
def generate_uuid():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex


class Profile(models.Model):
    api_key = models.CharField(default=generate_uuid, editable=False, unique=True, max_length=40)
```

Comment: It's so wrong! all Profile instances get same uuid value (you called uuid4() and it will be fixed in migration files)

Comment: @YaserKH My bad :( I've updated the answer :) Anyway thanks for the update

Comment: @JPG a uuid field will significantly outperform a charfield for most databases.